# how does byte array have invalid parameters for Image.FromStream

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, image, jpeg

im trying to populate the default carousel in the index of asp.net from an sql database.

i have an id (INT), title (VARCHAR), some text (VARCHAR) and an image (VARBINARY) for each row. to the left is my class in c# which i use to describe my sql database
[image]

below is my controller where i connect to sql database and fill a list with the data it has.

i try to convert the byte array to an image and add that image to ViewData["im1"] but i get an error saying the parameters of Image.FromStream are invalid

##################### my index code below where i deal with sql connection

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-896D683;Initial Catalog=ppp;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            var my_carousel_things = connection.Query<front_page>("select * from stuff_for_carrousel4");
            int A = 0;
            mi_converter m = new mi_converter();
            foreach (front_page p in my_carousel_things)
            {
                if (A == 0) { ViewData["id1"] = p.id; ViewData["title1"] = p.car_title; ViewData["text1"] = p.car_text; ViewData["im1"] = m.convert_byte_array_to_image(p.car_image);  }
                if (A == 1) { ViewData["id2"] = p.id; ViewData["title2"] = p.car_title; ViewData["text2"] = p.car_text; ViewData["im2"] = p.car_image; }
                if (A == 2) { ViewData["id3"] = p.id; ViewData["title3"] = p.car_title; ViewData["text3"] = p.car_text; ViewData["im3"] = p.car_image; }
                ViewData["im1 is null"] = "image 1 is set";
                A += 1;

            }
            ViewData["acount"] = A;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

############### my converter is below

```
    public class mi_converter
{
    public Image convert_byte_array_to_image(byte[] ar_in)
    {

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(ar_in))
        {   


            return Image.FromStream(ms);  // error happens here
        }
    }

}
```

}

finally here is the actual data from the sql database
[image]

Question) why are the parameters incorrect even though it is a byte array. how can i fix it.

i can provide any further information you need

Comment: Show your code and data as text, not images. Also, that's an awfully small image. What format does it have?

Comment: I appreciate the effort gone into making these screenshots nice, but if its actual code please just post the code. Its impossible for anyone in the future who has the same problem as you to google for this post using screenshots.

Comment: `i can provide any further information you need` please show the code and error message, we are not much help when we don't have anything to go on.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu that is exactly what their code does.

Comment: You are storing the bytes of a string (the image path), not the bytes of an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your binary column contains the following data:

```
43 3A 5C 55 73 65 72 73 5C 55 73 65 72 5C 44 65 73 6B 74 6F 70 5C 75 75 75 75 75 75 75 75 5C 70 32 2E 70 6E 67
```

Those are the ASCII codepoints for `C:\Users\User\Desktop\uuuuuuuu\p2.png`.

That is not image data, it's a file path. You need to write the actual image bytes into that column, not a file path.

So the problem is not in the code you show, but in the code that writes into the database.